# Torque wrench doesn't click

Tags: torque-wrench

I have a new and calibrated torque wrench that is for 2-15NM. When I'm tightening a bolt it doesn't seem to click even at 2NM no matter how hard I turn.

I tried using it against a same size hex key as the bolt by holding the hex key firmly and then it seems to click at fairly light pressure, but not when I'm actually tightening the bolt. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried tightening anything to a higher torque? 5,10? Does that work?

Comment: It's possible that either as a break-in type behavior or just how it is, it's just not clicking very loud. After using them for a long time, one gets used to the feeling of the handle shifting/reverberating as the case may be when torque is reached, and the actual click is a little secondary. I've used ones that were kind of like this.

Comment: I'll give that a try, as when I was trying to tighten the screw (socket cap) I didn't feel it or hear it click even though I could tighten it very hard at even when it was set to 2NM.

Comment: You might want to specify the make and model

Comment: If you go past the click, you can still tighten pretty hard. That’s one risk of mis-using the tool

Comment: It's this one: https://www.pro-bikegear.com/global/en-gb/accessories/Workshop_Tools/PRO_TL_TORQUE2 As you say I might not be feeling the click when actually tightening the actual screw, though I do feel it quite clearly when I'm just doing it against an allen key.

Comment: It's unclear what sort of torque wrench you have.  The simplest is an indicator style where you twist until the indicator points at the desired torque.  With other units you set the desired torque and twist until the wrench "slips".  As the wrench "slips", you will generally feel/hear a "click", but it's not guaranteed -- the "slip" is the indication you look for.  And there may be some other styles.  **Can you give us the brand/model of the wrench, and possibly a picture or link to an online description??**

Comment: @Daniel if I’m as clever as I think I am it’s the Pro PRTL0066 ;)

Comment: Are you sure there’s nothing in the instructions about dialling in a torque setting? I’ve used (larger) designs before where you pull out the base of the handle, thread in a torque value and then push the end of the handle back in again to set the value. I think.

Comment: Yes dialing is by unlocking it and then rotating it to desired setting and then locking again. I tried it again and it seems to be breaking now when I tighten, not sure what has changed, but at least I got a good sense for how much 2NM pressure feels like (it's quite light).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 3 possibilities, it’s not clicking because you aren’t turning hard enough, it’s clicking and you aren’t noticing it, or it’s broken. (Edit: 4th possibility it's a kind of break-in behaviour of the tool and the click is very gentle to begin with. Not sure why but seems to be what OP is reporting in comments. go carefully.)

I tried clicking mine at 2Nm holding the hex bit by hand and couldn’t do it. I had to twist the whole head of the torque wrench. Above 4Nm it’s quite hard to lever the head to click without an actual bolt to lever against.

I think you should try out a whole range of torques on suitable bolts, as well as finding another known torque wrench to compare against. Maybe seek out whoever calibrated it if practicable.

Edit: caveat; if one is a new user of torque wrenches go carefully with torque. A torque wrench will/should tell you when you achieve the torque spec., but it won't stop you tightening the bolt further if you continue forcing it. Excessive tightening can damage bolt threads.

Comment: Thanks, at 2NM I can get it to click against a hex key without so much pressure, at 10NM requires a lot more pressure, but still doable. I was definitely turning quite hard I though 2NM would be quite light pressure? I will try it on some more bolts though.

Comment: @Can if you’re holding both ends of the tool in the air to click in one hand against the other, it will feel like hard work because one end (the hex end) is levering a tiny distance from the fulcrum. It will feel like less force is needed when tightening a bolt because you can lever the whole length of the tool properly. 2Nm isn’t a ‘high’ torque but the force you need to apply always depends on the length of the lever.